# Android: How can I create a custom battery bar like this?

Tags: android, canvas, shapes, battery, indicator

[image]
[image]
[image]

the app called: SAO Widget

The battery bar have different color

and the bar will fit the unique shape background

also the battery percentage is tilted

using ImageView or ProgressBar?

Comment: This is image you have to set image as per battery percentage

Comment: I tried,but the image not fitting the background,also the battery percentage bar cannot be tilted

Comment: Its possible , you have to try for it

Comment: any hints?I googled but didn't find any way to tilt it,I'm newbie of android

Comment: Layout with some textviews, background pictures and images per battery percentage for the bar itself. You can have whatever text you want over images too.

Answer (score 0):

you can use progress bar with custom background and custom update colour to get this result, you can set progress bar after getting value of batter %age.

Comment: look at this question for custom progress bar
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9921621/android-progressbar-ui-custom-layout

Comment: Tried before,but still not found any method to tilt the bar progress,and the bar size not fitting the background too

Comment: dont try to title the bar, use images which looks like titled

Comment: if 100%,then the tilted part will overlapped the background?also 0% still have the tilted part looks like 5%?

Comment: make an XML progressbar_bg.xml set a titled image for progress update as well
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<clip
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:drawable="@drawable/progressbar_progressing"
    android:clipOrientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="left"/>

and use it like  android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progressbar_bg"

Comment: I try this later,but can I use JAVA canvas/paint/bitmap to live create image?

Comment: there can be another way, make a relative layout, make two imageViews in it one on another, and set background of imageView which is at front with your desired titled backgroud and set background of imageView behind with the image of your desired progress colour, increase width of imageView on behind according to battery %age