# Custom steps progress bar in android

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-custom-view

I want to create a custom progress bar that looks like this
https://i.stack.imgur.com/NK5Px.png
it should progress until it reaches one of the circles light it up and continue towards the next one until it reaches the last one.

What is the best approach to implement this?
- whether to extend progress bar and override onMeasure() & onDraw()
- or to create compound component with layout as root and populate it with progress bar
  and some circle like views.

**Update**
on the first approach i wonder how to make the progress bar half the size of the control and center it?
the other approach will make me use nested layouts, and seems to be more complex to create..What do you think? there is a completely different way to do it properly and easily?

Comment: Maybe [this similar SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9921621/android-progressbar-ui-custom-layout) question will help you?

Comment: not so much. i added an explanation to make clear what i aim for

Comment: What happens if you follow each approach?