# How I can create this type of textured progress bar "line-diag" (ninepatch?)?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view, android-progressbar

How I can create this type of textured progress bar "line-diag" (ninepatch?)?

[image]

I have read some threads and I think the solution would be using the images of type 9-patch. But I do not understand how to do it right. Can you explain how I can make this progress bar?

Comment: where is a progress here?

Comment: The image below (red color)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need a 9-patch here. Just change dynamically the width of your fill bar (I'm guessing that's the bright red one), and set the proper `scaleType`.-

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/bar_dark" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="matrix"
        android:src="@drawable/bar_light" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

---

For a `ProgressBar` component, this post could help.-

[Android ProgressBar UI custom layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9921621/android-progressbar-ui-custom-layout)

Comment: Not so simple. The image contains texture, if I change the width stripes are deformed. The bar should be scalable.

Comment: But scaleType is a property of imageview, I can not implement this solution using a progressbar.

Comment: Oh, I was thinking of a 'custom' progress bar instead of the native component. Can't tell if it's possible, but this thread looks promising.- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9921621/android-progressbar-ui-custom-layout

Comment: see this link: http://www.tiemenschut.com/how-to-customize-android-progress-bars/

Answer (score 0):

No need for a 9-patch.  You can use custom XML drawables.  Here is a good tutorial: [Android Tutorials for Beginners](http://learnandroideasily.blogspot.com/2013/05/custom-progress-bar-in-android.html)

Google "**android custom progress bar**" for more examples.