# Create rectangle progress bar in android

Tags: android, android-progressbar

[image]

Hello, I want to create progress bar which should look like above image. Here, I have created one like below image.

[image]

Below is the xml file which I created in drawable folder under res,

### progress.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/white"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip>
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="@color/lightgreen"/>
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

But I want exactly the same progress bar as image 1 when progress continues, how to implement it?

Comment: Maybe [this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9921621/1051783) will help you?

Comment: i think if your use right image in background with rectangle corners.it will make you able to get what you want in the image you have shown in your question.You will just require to write a customize style for your progress bar.

Comment: @thumber nirmal Check out my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change xml to mention start-color, end-color and center.

Mention color values properly: start-color: left, end-color: right and center.

Comment: hello. I implemented ur solution but I can't get the exact output, I can see only 2 colors here, 1: background color of progress bar and 2: when progess bar continues then only 1 color changes, it doesn't effect when it reaches at center.