# Android How to make step Progressbar

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-progressbar

I want to make progress bar as a step bar like below. Can anyone please help me how to achieve this.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13271044/4385913)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android ProgressBar UI custom layout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9921621/android-progressbar-ui-custom-layout)

Comment: Its not duplicate. That is for adding image for progress Start and End. But this is to start progress and end where ever you want in middle of the bar. like State.

Comment: I would also like to have something like this.